# Name lookup and point of declaration concepts

Tags: c++, namespaces

I'm interested in a formal couplig between a `point of declaration` and a `name-lookup` concepts. In particular, when a `nested-name-specifier` denoted a namespace, an unqualified name lookup produce a set of declaration as follows: `N4296::3.4.3.2 [namespace.qual]`

> For a namespace `X` and name `m`, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   `S(X,m)` is defined as follows: Let `S0(X,m)` be the set of all
>   declarations of `m` in `X` and the inline namespace set of `X` (7.3.1). If
>   `S0(X,m)` is not empty, `S(X,m)` is `S0(X,m)`; otherwise, `S(X,m)` is the
>   union of `S(Ni,m)` for all namespaces `Ni` nominated by using-directives
>   in `X` and its inline namespace set.

Let me provide a couple examples:

1.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    int b = 42;
}

int a = A::a; //Error

namespace A
{
    int a = 24;
}

int main(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c27a2260df3b916a)**

2.

```
#include <iostream>

namespace A
{
    int b = 42;
}

namespace A
{
    int a = 24;
}

int a = A::a; //OK

int main(){ std::cout << a << std::endl; }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f7340c4715c0b8)**

The rule I provided has nothing to do with the point of declaration concept, but in fact we can see that it does. So the Standard implicitly assumes that the name's `m` point of declaration should be before the point where the name is used. I think  it should be specified explicitly. Maybe I lost the clause where it was specified... if so, couldn't you point me out to that one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [basic.scope.namespace] (§3.3.6/1), emphasis mine:

> A namespace
>   member name has namespace scope. Its potential scope includes its namespace from the name’s **point of
>   declaration (3.3.2) onwards**

`a` can only be found in `namespace A` *after* it is declared. So example (1) is invalid because `a` hasn't been declared yet and example (2) is valid because it has been.